# Google sheets query order by SUM

Tags: google-sheets-query

I am trying to do this query:

```
=query(indirect($B$1), "select D, E, F, SUM(H) group by D,E,F pivot G order by SUM(H)",1)
```

It looks OK, but results in an error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_AGG_IN_ORDER_WHEN_PIVOT: H
>   If I try

```
=query(indirect($B$1), "select D, E, F, SUM(H) group by D,E,F pivot G order by H",1) the I get:
```

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
>   COL_IN_ORDER_MUST_BE_IN_SELECT: `H`

```
=query(indirect($B$1), "select D, E, F, SUM(H) group by D,E,F pivot G order by D",1) works OK.
```

1. How to order by SUM(H)?
2. Any idea how to order by SUM(H) for specific value of G (like in Pivot table in google sheets)?

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: I solved this problem through google apps script, but it took much more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use **ORDER BY** and **PIVOT** at the same time. But you can use 2 query nested functions. In the first one using **PIVOT** and the second one with the **ORDER BY**.

Remmember that in the second query you must use de Col1, Col2, ... notation:

```
=query(query(indirect($B$1)
             , "select D, E, F, SUM(H) 
                group by D, E, F 
                pivot G"
             , 1)
       , "select *
          ORDER BY Col4"
       , 1)
```